# Some startup commands not executing

Tags: startup

Added xrandr --output eDP-1 --gamma 0.9:0.85:0.9 to the start up commands but its not executing on startup, even when xset m 0/1 0 executes.

Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgOtC.jpg

Comment: As it got bumped to community I wonder If my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

Some commands always needed some delay for me, so try adding sleep 3 && before the command.

Other option to try is to make a new file in home (eg. Startup.sh). Open it with scratch and instert:

```
 #!/bin/bash
     Your command
```

Make the file executable (e.g. with right click-> properties) and put the location of the file in startup applications /home/your name/startup.sh

You can even try combining the two, adding sleep 3 && before your command in the file.